# how to fetch uploaded file in local folder on jsp page?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have written program to upload file and that file is stored in local system folder and it's path is stored into sql database table. Now I have multiple records which are fetched from database using **(select * form dmsfiles)**. For each record there is "Edit" option then user can change file on same id. So how to bring that file on JSP page from local system folder?